# Delete specific object in MongoDB collectionn

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In MongoDB I have a User collection, where each user has a games object Array with many objects inside. I need to delete a specific game of a certain user (in this case lOrrlB).

JS

I make a Delete request where gameViewing = lOrrlB

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: '/games/' + gameViewing,
    data: {
      toDelete: gameViewing
    },
    dataType: "json"
  })
```

App.JS

I search for the user and try to deletOne the corresponding game, but in Node I get "Cannot read property 'gameToDelete' of undefined". Also I'm not convinced about the "key" parameter.

```
app.route('/games/:gameId')
.delete(function(req, res){
  let gameToDelete = req.body.toDelete;
  User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, foundUser) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      if (foundUser) {
        User.games[gameToDelete].deleteOne(
          {key: req.body.toDelete},
          function(err) {
              if(!err){
                console.log("Deleted!");
              } else {
                console.log("Error!");
              }
            }
        )
      }
    }
  })
});
```

[image]

Model

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  googleId: String,
  profileImage: String,
  myCollection: {
    type: Object,
    default: Object
  },
  games: {
    type: Object,
    default: Object
  }
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/12345",
    userProfileUrl: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({
        googleId: profile.id,
        username: profile.displayName,
        profileImage: profile.photos[0].value,
        myCollection: catalogDb,
        games: {}
      },
      function(err, user) {
        return cb(err, user);
      });
  }
));
```

Comment: do you need to delete a specific game of a specific user?

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: @NikitaMazur Yes, user can delete their own games

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc I've updated the question with the model and schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) is what you need:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, {
  $unset: {
    [`games.${gameToDelete}`]: ""
  }
}, ...)
```

Comment: .delete(function(req, res){ let gameToDelete = req.body.toDelete; User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, { $unset: {[`games.${gameToDelete}`]: ""}}, ...)}); This results into syntax error

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
I tried and verified but still different forms of syntax error } or ).

Comment: replace ... with your callback

Comment: Oh right. I had trouble with all the brackets but now it's working.